# Jekyll collections only show some items

Tags: jekyll

I am migrating some items from `posts` to `collections` in jekyll.

When they were posts, all items rendered correctly. I moved all the files into an `_items` directory and added the following to the `_config.yml`

```
collections:
  items:
    output: true
    permalink: /things/:path/
```

I then accessed the collection in a page (title is in each file's yaml front-mater) for debugging using:

```
{% for item in site.items %}
  {{ item.title }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

- Only some of the files in the `_items` folder show up.
- When I look at `_site` I see some raw `.md` files in a `items` folder and some generated pages in a `things` folder. These generated files match those showing in the page above.

I have tried the following:

- looked at encoding to check that it is not UTF-8 with BOM signature
- check line endings are consistent - `CRLF`
- looked at file names and sub-folders

Any ideas what could have happened?

### Update

This has been fixed as of https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/4290 which will go live with version 3.1 - see which version Github Pages uses on https://pages.github.com/versions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it was because there was whitespace after the initial `---` in the front-matter of some of the posts.

I have created an issue on the Jekyll issue tracker at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4017

You can see a demonstration of the issue at http://elliz.github.io/jekyll-collection-issue/